# Create login for multiple users with customized content with TYPO3 11.5.21

Tags: authentication, frontend, typo3

First of all, I must confess that I'm very, very new in TYPO3, therefore, my questions might be a bit confusing or not properly understandable. So, please be patient with me.

As already stated in the title, I want to create a login page for multiple users and every user  should see a customized content, for example some pdf files or slides.

I was able to create a login page and it's working but I have no clue what's happening afterwards. I'm searching for a solution since days but the TYPO3 documentation is super shitty, especially for beginners like me.

My idea was to work with a MySQL database (I don't even know if this is possible). After the login  all data about the customer are read from the database and defined files (some pdf and slides) should be shown.

Is this possible like that? Or how is the usual way to do that?

I'm happy for every hint!

Thanks a lot in advance :-)

cheers,
expikx

I tried to find a solution online but without success

Answer (score 0):

you need a custom extension which will render the files based on the logged in user. By using the extension "extension builder" you can create a first version of your extension very quickly which can be used as base.

If you are german speaking, take a look at the videos of Stefan, e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dhRBvTZoPQM& which document how to create an extension as well

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Login of TYPO3 you can also use the access-management from TYPO3 for FrontEnd content:
for each erecord (page, content, news, ...) you can decide which group(!) of users can see it.

Each record in TYPO3 normaly contains a field (in the access tab) to select which groups can see this record.

It's up to you to define the groups each user belongs to.
And each group can access some content. TYPO3 merges it and even can give access to one record to multiple groups.

Regarding files like PDFs: if you do not need absolute access restrictions it would be possible to only list links to the files for the apropriate groups. (other users, even not logged in users could access the files if they know the URL)

e.g.:

You have users in three groups like owner of product A, product B, product C.
Of course there are owners of multiple Products.

For each group you can provide content like manuals, updates or lists of service points.

First you can give access to the pages about each product only to member of the matching group. All the content of that pages are visible only after login and if the user belongs to that group.

But you also can have mixed pages:
Maybe news where all updates are shown. Although each news record has (at least) one group to be shown to.
There could be one page with the news plugin to show all news. After login only those records are shown which belong to the groups of the user, other records are hidden. (not logged in users can see only records not restricted to any group)

---

If you want a individuality of content by person you need a group for each user.
If you want the user to select by himself what his interests are you need a FE plugin where he can select his memberships of individual groups.